# git subtree command adds files to parent tree

Tags: git, git-subtree

I ran this command:

```
git subtree add --prefix=config --squash git@github.com:user/repo.git master
```

in the root folder I committed changes and pushed to remote.
The subtree files in the config folder were included.

Should I .gitignore the config directory? Why does it include the subtree files in parent git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I `.gitignore` the config directory?

No.

> Why does it include the subtree files in parent git repo?

Because that is not a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (which only records at the parent level the SHA1 of the subrepo).
That is a [subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree) ([presented here](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/)), which does include one repo into another.

[image: https://3kllhk1ibq34qk6sp3bhtox1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/BeforeAfterGitSubtreeDiagram.png]

Comment: so how do i make it read-only from the parent repo? i want to make it modifiable only from the subtree / inner repo

Comment: @AlexanderMills A Git repo does not have the notion of "partial" read/write: If you can clone a repo, you can modify any part of it. What you can do is setup a pre-receive hook (if you have access to the server) or a webhook (if you don't, as in github.com: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) in order to *reject* any commit which includes modifications to files you don't want (ie files at the parent level).